# What does 'char x[]' mean?

Tags: c++, c

I have a struct like this:

```
struct A 
{   
  char x[];
};
```

What does it mean? When I do something like:

```
A a;
a.x = "hello";
```

gcc throws an error saying:

```
error: incompatible types in assignent of 'const char [6]' to 'char [0u]'
```

Comment: This appears to be C++. The example provided won't compile as C because a plain `A` is not defined at that point (`struct A` is defined). `c` tag removed.

Comment: @pmg The example provided won't compile as C++ either. `test.cc:3:16: error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'x'`

Comment: @pmg: isn't the code not compiling the reason of the question?

Comment: There are two reasons that it doesn't compile in C++, but only one in C. Not sure why this is tagged C++ only if the highest voted answer is correctly about a C feature...

Comment: `c` tag reintroduced. [ebascomp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/184012/ebasconp) should choose the language s/he is using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a C99 "flexible array member".
See here for gcc specifics: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_42.html

Comment: May also be useful to note that this is an error in C++ (question is tagged for two languages)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in C++, you can't have an array of unspecified size. Also, you should use a pointer instead of an array if you want to assign to them string literals:

```
struct A 
{   
  char* x;
};
```

Comment: For the downvoter, the question is tagged "c++", I just forgot to say that applies to C++. I don't know about C99.

Comment: Your answer is correct for C++ but wrong for C (C99). (I'm not the downvoter though.)

Answer (score 2):

This structure has a C99 *flexible array member*. As such it's invalid to declare variables of type `struct A`, but you can declare a variable of type `struct A *` (pointer to `struct A`) and use `malloc` to obtain memory for it as:

```
struct A *a = malloc(sizeof *a + strlen(mystring) + 1);
strcpy(a->x, mystring);
```

Answer (score -1):

char x[] can be read as "x is a pointer to an array of char for which we have not yet allocated the necessary memory". However you either have to specify a contant size (char x[6]) or declare this as a pointer (char* x)

a.x = "hello" does not work because a.x does not point to any memory space you could have allocated. Additionally, the compiler complains about assigning something supposed to be constant (the string) to something that could be changed by the program.

You either have to declare x constant or copy the string manually using a function such as strcpy.

For instance:

```
struct A 
{   
    char *x;
};

A a; 
a.x = new char[6]; 
strcpy(a.x, "Hello");
```

Comment: Oops, did not know about char x[] being allowed in C.

Comment: This does not compile: `incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [0u]’`. That's because `char x[]` is an array; you can't assign a pointer to it.